# Another way to save streaming

Tags: javascript, streaming

I don't like `MediaStream Recording API`. If you pause a stream or return back for several seconds - it will record this too. And the main reason is that fps is much lower and there are freezes (which were not on streams). So it changes data and it is bad.

I want just to save streaming in original quality - like joining parts which are downloaded one by one. So it should work if even video is paused because the loading of parts continues.

It is only about streams (from internet) in the `<video>` element. No webcam.

**Do another ways to save streaming exist?**
Maybe it is possible with `Media Streams API`, `Streams API` or `WebRTC API`?

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API
```

Or maybe some API of extensions?

Saving though the console is quite good for me. No need to create a user interface for saving.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this all to be client side? You can run a server and stream WebRTC to it. I created [save-to-disk](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/save-to-disk) to show how.

I am not aware of any other solutions Client side, but I haven't had to look for a solution before!

Comment: Only client side. I don't have a server.

Comment: If you are just deleting with a remote media file you could just download it directly? I am not exactly sure what you are doing, but why not pull the `src` tag and `fetch` it yourself. I think I am missing details of your issue, but in general I don't think you are gonna get an alternative API.

Comment: No, it is about online streams. Now I see in DevTools that it comes in parts (*.ts files) with 2 seconds. And no long video stored on the server after that. The thing is to join them with some API. I don't understand the idea with `src`. Can it work in this case?

Comment: Yea! So I would (via Javascript) get access to the m3u8 file, that will give you a list of everything you need to download. I use `youtube-dl` to download HLS playlists (out of the browser though)

Comment: And how to do this? 1 *.ts file comes with 1 *.m3u8 file. I see that there are names (not links) of only 3 *.ts files inside 1 *.m3u8 file (because it is a real-time stream). I don't want to download these little videos manually and join in some external program. If 1 file has 1 second, then 1 hour = 3600 files. I want to join them in Chrome with some API.

Comment: How can the idea with `src` and `fetch` help?